# Recursive Function, Saving DynamicPreparedStatement

Tags: mysql, function, recursion

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tmpUser`@`%` FUNCTION `getUniqueIdForTable`(VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS varchar(250) CHARSET utf8mb4
BEGIN
    SET @id = MD5(NOW()+RAND());
    SET @stmntSTR = CONCAT("SELECT id FROM ",@tablename," WHERE id = @id"); 

    IF NOT isempty(EXECUTE stmnt) THEN #experimental        
        return getUniqueIdForTable(@tablename);
    ELSE 
        return @id;
    END IF;     
END
```

Hello i am trying to create a recursive Function to create a ID that is dynamic and isnt dupped.
My problem is getting the RESULT of stmntSTR and check it for Elements

Comment: If you are trying to dynamically create tables I would say with 99% certainty you are doing something very wrong in your design process

Comment: i am doing this function dynamicly because i call it with a trigger and it needs to be uniqe but should not be Autoincrement, normaly i use java to add id but its called in a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a MySQL built-in function that generates an UUID : [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). You can use it instead of writting one yourself.

---

If you still want to do it yourself, you don't need to create a recursive function for that purpose.

A `WHILE` loop should be enough

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tmpUser`@`%` FUNCTION `getUniqueIdForTable`(VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS varchar(250) CHARSET utf8mb4
BEGIN
    SET @found = 0;
    WHILE (FOUND = 0)
        SET @id = MD5(NOW()+RAND());
        SET @stmntSTR = CONCAT("SELECT id FROM ",@tablename," WHERE id = @id"); 
        IF isempty(EXECUTE stmnt) THEN
            SET @found = 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN @id;
END
```